Spring Boot pass a default value in return
How can return a default value in else?
@GetMapping("/byemail/{email}")
public ResponseEntity<IndirizzoDto> getIndirizzoByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {

    Indirizzo indirizzo = indirizzoService.filtraPerEmail(email);
    if (indirizzo != null) {
        // convert entity to DTO
        IndirizzoDto indirizzoResponse = modelMapper.map(indirizzo, IndirizzoDto.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(indirizzoResponse);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();  --> How can I pass a default value?
    }
}

I want a default value of type json

Can you try passing null to build() in else case?

I want to pass {"Address":"via Roma, 11"} or No address

Something like this will work
@GetMapping("/byemail/{email}")
public ResponseEntity<IndirizzoDto> getIndirizzoByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    IndirizzoDto defaultIndirizzoDto = new IndirizzoDto(); // however default is created
    Indirizzo indirizzo = indirizzoService.filtraPerEmail(email);
    if (indirizzo != null) {
        // convert entity to DTO
        IndirizzoDto indirizzoResponse = modelMapper.map(indirizzo, IndirizzoDto.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(indirizzoResponse);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(defaultIndirizzoDto);


The defaultIndirizzoDto can be populated with some default values like user wants, e.g. defaultIndirizzoDto.setAddress("via Roma, 11");

thanks it works!

@user27593256 would you accept the answer if you're happy
